# Jqgrid unchecked value willl not be removed from textarea

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid for displaying my table. in that i need to get a particular column values in a textarea by selecting the row using checkbox. if i select a row in the grid it was added in to the textarea but if i unselect the row the column value will not be removed from the text area.

Comment: Can you share the code or you could clear the text area after unselected.

Comment: var selRow = jQuery("#lst_Mobile1").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');  //get selected rows

           
            var flag = jQuery(this).find('#' + id + ' input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked');

            var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(id);
            MobileID = rowData['mobile_regid'];
            if (flag == true) {

                $("#txtarea").get(0).value += MobileID + '\n';


            }
            else {
                
                                $('textarea').val('');
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var selRow = jQuery("#lst_Mobile1").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow'); //get selected rows 
var flag = jQuery(this).find('#' + id + ' input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked'); 
var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(id); MobileID = rowData['mobile_regid']; 
if (flag == true) 
{ 
 $("#txtarea").get(0).value += MobileID + '\n';
} 
else 
{ 
 $("#txtarea").val($("#txtarea").val().replace( MobileID + '\n',""));
}
```

Edited: after the comment.

Comment: Sorry, it clear entire data from textarea i need to remove that particular column value appended in textarea

Comment: if i select a row using checkbox that mobileID is appended in to the textarea if i uncheck the same row it will clear previosly appended all mobileID's from text area.